# jquery to select and activate all items of a particular class on click of a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, css-selectors

I'm new to Javascript, but I have come across an issue at my work to do some javascript. We are customising a product for customers to create forms. The form objects (text fields, drop downs etc) are present in menu. Each of these objects can be selected individually or multiple by using Ctrl Key. We have been asked to enable radio buttons so that customers can select them easily. Each of these are in groups, so can be selected easily.

For eg.  (a) Select all customer contact options (b) Customer organisation details
Once selected, they should be draggable and dropped into the form.

Hence the requirement in technical terms are

1. Radio buttons for various groups (Customer Contact options etc..)
2. Once a radio button is selected, activate the relevant class of objects.
3. Initiate the drag/move function

   The HTML snippet is something like..  //replaced < to ( to put as code

> ```
>     (div class="FormElementMain" style="TOP: 5px; LEFT: 10px" FieldType="Label")
>   (span class="contactOptionsLabel" style="width: 50px")Mobile Number(/span)
> (/div)
> (div class="FormElementMain" style="TOP: 5px; LEFT: 20px" FieldType="Label")
>   (span class="contactOptionsLabel" style="width: 50px")Tel Number(/span)
> (/div)
> (div class="FormElementMain" style="TOP: 5px; LEFT: 30px" FieldType="Label")
>   (span class="orgDetailsLabel" style="width: 50px")Job Designation(/span)
> (/div)
> ```

The product code(function) where we need to bind is:

```
function selectLabelClass(object)
{
    
    object.addClass("highlightDiv");   // Just to highlight the div class so a shade appears around the text
    var currentWrapper=object;
    
    CurrentObject.push(new MoveObject(currentWrapper));
    currentWrapper.draggable({ grid: [GridSizeX, GridSizeY], containment: ".ui_fieldsetset" });
    
    DisplayProperties();
}
```

Hence once the Radiobutton is clicked, I'm trying to initiate the Label Class as

```
$("#selectLabelRadioButton").live("click",
        function () 
        {
            selectLabelClass(".contactOptionsLabel");
        });
        
 });
```

Its not working though :(
Can anyone suggest how to activate a class/group of objects using a radio button

On a separate note, I tried a simple test and it works.
// Just to highlight all objects of the class using a red border.
// So really just wanted to know how the .css can be replaced by another custom function

```
  $("#selectLabelRadioButton").click(function(){
   $(".selectLabelClass").css("border","3px solid red");
 });
```

Comment: Do you get errors in the console? (I'm sure you do, it's just to point it out than you need to look for this kind of things...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what about all of your code which is not in your question.

But you just passed a string instead of a jQuery object to the `selectLabelClass` which expect to get a jQuery object...

Change this: `selectLabelClass(".contactOptionsLabel");`
To this: `selectLabelClass($(".contactOptionsLabel"));`

```
$("#selectLabelRadioButton").live("click", function() {
    selectLabelClass($(".contactOptionsLabel"));
});​
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out. not working mate. May be the "live" which I've put is wrong.

Comment: @diaryfolio. From the bit I see, it looks like you have many others problems as well. When you write code, test if after every couple of lines. if you are not familiar with javascript\jquery, test it after each line. Am I right?

Comment: yes mate. I did like that only. If you see i put a sample thing to colour the border and it worked. But the thing I'm unsure is how to call a function using a jquery selector.